# SSIS Execute process call to dtexec.exe failing

Tags: ssis

I am trying to set up an SSIS package that calls other packages via a execute process task.  All was working fine until I decided to try to execute the packages with a configuration file.  The original expression was:

```
"/REP E /f " +  @[User::screenName] + ".dtsx "
```

I changed it to

```
"/REP E /conf .\\<myconfigfile>.dtsConfig /f " +  @[User::screenName] + ".dtsx"
```

which got me `The process exit code was "4" while the expected was "0".`

and

```
"/REP E /conf d:\\<dir1>\\<dir2>\\packages\\<myconfigfile>.dtsConfig /f " +  @[User::screenName] + ".dtsx"
```

which got me `The process exit code was "6" while the expected was "0".`

If I take the command and run it from a command line, like so:

```
dtexec.exe /REP E /conf  .\<myconfigfile>.dtsConfig /f <myssispackage>.dtsx
```

or

```
dtexec.exe /REP E /conf "w:\<dir1>\<dir2>\<myconfigfile>.dtsConfig" /f <mySSISpackage>.dtsx
```

it works fine.

Is there any way at all I can get a better error message?  I think there's something about the expression that's causing problems.

Comment: Why don't you use the standard Execute SSIS PAckage task?

Comment: I probably had a reason when I started this endeavor, but can't recall it.  I'll look that task up and see what comes of it.  Thanks!

Comment: It's the usual workaround to run a 32 bit process from a 64 bit process. According to this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, return code 4 = "unable to locate the requested package.", return code 6 = "syntactic or semantic errors in the command line" (admittedly unhelpful). The other option is to use DTEXECUI.exe to build your command line

Comment: An odd wrinkle.  I just ran the package that runs the other packages from the command line and it works.  It only seems to be having this problem from Visual Studio.

Comment: Like it says in the answer.... VS probably has a different path and uses a different dtexec. It should tell you in the console what version it is using each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to target the correct `dtexec` executable. Maybe your PATH is different when executed from the command line to the one used in Execute Process task.

A good suggestion from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/126293/ is to search the hard drive for all appearances of it. There are very detailed instructions in that article for more than that.

Edit: Ouch, maybe exit code has something to tell us?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility#exit

4: The utility was unable to locate the requested package. The package could not be found.

6: The utility encountered an internal error of syntactic or semantic errors in the command line.

Errors of type 6 could be related to the escape characters. 
What happens if you try to add some extra-escaped double quotes?

```
"/REP E /conf \"d:\\<dir1>\\<dir2>\\packages\\<myconfigfile>.dtsConfig\" /f " +  @[User::screenName] + ".dtsx"
```

Comment: Ok, it was an issue of VS running from somewhere else.  I'm now working on that angle.